# how can i get the custom email template name(label) by passing its template id?

Tags: magento-1.9, template, email, custom

I have created a custom select field in system->configuration->sales->payment method to select the custom email template.I got its id=20 by using this code

```
 $storeId = Mage::app()->getStore()->getId();
 $text_field_value=Mage::getStoreConfig('payment/wirpayment/email_template2',$storeId);
```

but I need its template name from this template id.How can i get it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
echo Mage::getModel('core/email_template')->load(1)->getTemplateCode();
```

Replace 1 with your template Id.